# SQL: Insert from table where < >

Tags: sql, insert, where-clause

I have the following tables:

- `Tp (a INT, b var)`
- `Ts (c int, d var)`
- `Tt (x tp, y ts)`

And I want insert into tt values where a > c
I tried:

```
INSERT INTO TT (X,Y)
SELECT tp.a, ts.c From tp, ts
WHERE a>c;
```

But I get that `X` is of type tp but expression is of type `integer`.
How can I solve this matter just using `INSERT INTO ...` ?

Comment: Which datatypes did you say Tt has?

Comment: post your table sql code

Comment: What is your **exact** error message?

Comment: Don't you need to insert a,b into X?

Comment: What database are you using?  What is `var`?  What type is `tp`?  What type is `ts`?

Comment: That's what I have. Thank you for your feedback. :)

 CREATE TABLE Tp( 
 A INT, 
 B VARCHAR 
);

CREATE TABLE Ts( 
 C INT, 
 D VARCHAR 
);

CREATE TABLE TT(
 id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
 X Tp,
 Y Ts 
);

INSERT INTO TT (X,Y)
 SELECT tp.a, ts.c From tp, ts
 WHERE a>c
;

Comment: Which dbms lets you use other tables as column datatypes when you create a new table? Or is this some kind of foreign key notation perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

**x**'s type must be integer or must be same with a's type .

Comment: Ok, I get that. But how do I do inset into Tt values where a > c ?